# How to make local character insensitive search with regex in MongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I want to make a search and let's say my keyboard is English. But in the database, there are some data including Turkish charachters:

"İstanbul"

"İzmir"

etc. Because I don't have "**İ**" in my keyboard, I never be able to find these 2 data in my queries.

What is the best way to do it?

UPDATE:

In NodeJS, I have following function to convert Turkish characters into English alikes:

```
function convertTurkishToEnglish(trStr){
   return S(trStr)
      .replaceAll('ı', 'i')
      .replaceAll('ö', 'o')
      .replaceAll('ü', 'u')
      .s; 
}
```

But I cannot apply it to the data in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a unicode escape sequence `\u0130` to identify `İ`

Comment: The easier way is to replace this character a dot to match any character instead: `/.stanbul/i`. But `/\u0130stanbul/i` is a better solution.

Comment: But my problem is English keyboard. If someone write "Istanbul" to find "İstanbul", he cannot find. And "Omer" for "Ömer" for example.

Comment: @Burak [here](http://tufangorel.blogspot.in/2009/07/unicode-characters-corresponding-to.html) is a list of all turkish unicode characters...you can replace those particular ascii characters with turkish unicode characters before matching..

Answer (score 1):

Three options come to mind:

1. Enhance the data to include an additional field that represents the "to English" version of the text (using your `convertTurkishToEnglish` function for example) (you might be able to use a MapReduce function to build a new table that has what you need).
2. Investigate using a search engine like ElasticSearch or Solr for a more exhaustive search option
3. Increase the complexity of your regular expressions to include all of the combinations of character replacement whenever text is searched (at runtime you'd build these search strings):

   `db.users.find({"username": { $regex: "\u0130|ian", $options : "i" } })`

In the above code snippet, it's looking for `İ` or `i`. You'd need to do this for any other Turkish characters. (It was looking for "Ian" for example).

Comment: could you please explain the 3rd option? If you can give an example for two characters, it will enough.

Comment: searching for `i` would for example, build a regex that searches for `İ` or `i` (which is the | in the example), and then lowercase.